# Jenkins DSL: LDAP Roles

Tags: jenkins, ldap, jenkins-job-dsl

In our company, all Jenkins jobs are only created via the Jenkins DSL. Our Jenkins permissions are controlled via LDAP. For this we use the Jenkins LDAP Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/LDAP+Plugin) version 1.20.

Currently individual LDAP users are authorized:

```
freeStyleJob ('Jobname') {
[...]
    authorization {
        permission('hudson.model.Item.Build', 'User1')
        permission('hudson.model.Item.Build', 'User2')
        [...]
    }
[...]
}
```

I would like to use LDAP groups instead of authorizing individual users:

```
freeStyleJob ('Jobname') {
[...]
    authorization {
        permission('hudson.model.Item.Build', 'LDAPROLE_BUILD')
    }
[...]
}
```

How do I have to adjust my DSL files to use LDAP roles instead of single users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is exactly the way you have to do it:

```
freeStyleJob ('Jobname') {
[...]
    authorization {
        permission('hudson.model.Item.Build', 'LDAPROLE_BUILD')
    }
[...]
}
```

If you want to give multiple LDAP Roles the rights to build you have to do it with an array:

```
freeStyleJob ('Jobname') {
[...]
    authorization {
        permission('hudson.model.Item.Build', ['LDAPROLE_BUILD1', 'LDAPROLE_BUILD2'])
    }
[...]
}
```

It is also usefull to give the role that has rights to build also the rights to cancel a build `hudson.model.Item.Cancel`

To give a LDAP role only rights to 'read' a job you can use Read and Workspace:

- `hudson.model.Item.Read`
- `hudson.model.Item.Workspace`